# How to read a variable from another script in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want that when the player have low health, a red screen (already did a loop animation for it) with an animation plays (it plays automatically that's why im just activating the gameObject),I tried to do it with saving the value in a text file and read it from the other script, but is not optimized and it doesn't work, what it looks like :

```
    public void CreateText()
    {
        string path = Application.dataPath + "/Datas/data";
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.WriteAllText(path, "" + health);
        }
        else
        {
            File.Delete(path);
            File.WriteAllText(path, "" + health);
        }
    }
```

In the other Script :

```
    public int health = 1000;
    public string health0;
    public string path = Application.dataPath + "/Datas/data";
    public GameObject healthbar;

    void Update()
    {
        Int32.TryParse(health0, out health);
        File.ReadLines(path);
        if (health <= 600)
        {
            healthbar.SetActive(true);
        }
        else
        {
            if (healthbar.activeInHierarchy == true)
            {
                healthbar.SetActive(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't need a file for this, you need a reference to the other script.
It's a bit hard to help clearly without seeing the rest of the code, can you post both scripts?

Comment: Cadmonkey33 I did what I wanted to do in the same actual script and is working, but I will search abt references tho, thx for your answer!!

Comment: Get a reference to your script and access its public field .. going through FileIO is damn expensive and completely overkill for basically any application out there ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access scripts from other scripts just by getting the script component (like any other component). Lets say you have a game object `A` with an attached script `ScriptA` and also a game object `B` with a script `ScriptB`. To access `ScriptB` from `ScriptA`, you would need to:

```
class ScriptA : Monobehaviour {

    void Method() {
        GameObject b = GameObject.Find("B");  // get somehow a reference to B
        ScriptB scriptB = b.GetComponent<ScriptB>();  // get access to the script
        // now you can access all public stuff from the script
        scriptB.publicAttribute ...
        scriptB.publicMethod() ...
    }
}
```

For such runtime logic like you have with the healthbar, you should not use the filesystem. This is really an unnecessary detour.